# What 80/90's mini-series/pilot has Virtual Reality tech that killed its users?

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi

I remember a mini-series or failed pilot from the late-80s or early 90s.

A Jimmy Smits-type cop investigated a new addictive Virtual Reality tech that kills its users. It used a small coin-sized disk that plugged into your brain.

The bad guy’s HQ was the Los Angeles Pacific Design Center (the Big Blue Whale building). The main character's BFF was a black guy who overdosed and dragged the cop into the case.

Comment: http://www.denofgeek.com/movies/virtual-reality/34409/the-top-12-virtual-reality-movies-of-the-1990s

Comment: How did it plug into your brain? Like a disk drive slot? Or did it stick into a head-mounted device?

Comment: Not much help here; http://www.imdb.com/search/text?realm=title&field=locations&q=Pacific+Design+Center

Comment: Disc went behind the ear, or maybe a cigerrate pack sized box

Comment: TekWar was it.  Thank you all.   I was incarcerated at the time, so it must have been the pilot I viewed.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds kind of like [TekWar](http://TekWar), the 1994 TV series based on the William Shatner novels. "Tek" is an addictive single-use chip that's a sort of cyber-drug.

> Set in the year 2045, the series follows Jake Cardigan, a former
>   police officer who lost his badge after being framed for dealing in
>   tek (an illicit narcotic-like substance) and murdering his fellow
>   officers on a bust.

Jake is played by Greg Evigan, though, who's not exactly a Jimmy Smits type, but Eugene Clark plays the fellow former cop who drags Jake into becoming a private investigator.
[image: Eugene Clark and Greg Evigan]

Answer (score 0):

It could be Strange Days.
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114558/

Early 90's film, set in New Year 2000.
People use "squids" (neural interface) to record and playback memories. The recording itself would be about like what you describe in size.